# Why is it that $\left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} K_{\alpha} \right)^c = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} K_{\alpha}^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why does $$\left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} K_{\alpha} \right)^c = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} K_{\alpha}^c$$ Explain why the union of open sets is open? My teacher said it is, but I don't understand why? Any help

Comment: Are you familiar with why (a) the complement of an open set is closed, and (b) the intersection of arbitrarily many closed sets is closed?  If not, what are the definitions of "open" and "closed" that your teacher gave you?

Comment: Why so many people are asking about infinite DeMorgan laws in the past few days?! It's uncanny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an explanation only if you already know that any intersection of closed sets is closed. This is because if $K_{\alpha}$ is open for all $\alpha\in A$, then $K_{\alpha}^c$ is closed, so $\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}K_{\alpha}^c$ is a closed set. Therefore, its complement—which is equal to $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} K_{\alpha}$, indeed—is open.